# Find the axis around which there is the most rotation?

Tags: java, algorithm, 3d, motion-detection

Given a 3d rotation, is there a way to compute the axis around which the largest component of the rotation happens?

To ground this in the actual task I'm attempting: I am getting data from a smartphone gyroscope and I want to figure out what axis the user is turning their phone around but without knowing anything other than the absolute rotation. This is using Java and Android.

Comment: Please provider how the rotation is given.  Is it giving an askew axis somehow?

Comment: It's in the form of a Quaternion from an Android SensorEventListener. The rotation is around an absolute axis where Y is true North, Z is the perpendicular to the ground plane and X is YxZ. So I cant know for sure that the phone will be aligned with any given orthogonal axis.

Comment: I'd take the axis of rotation of the quaternion (X, Y, Z components, that's not normalized but it's fine) and compute dot product with each axis, the largest absolute value is the axis you pick. Be mindful about quaternions with near-one W components (near-zero X, Y, Z components).

Comment: Actually, since the axes you are considering are (I suppose) the X, Y and Z axes, just pick the component with the largest absolute value, and that is the axis.

Comment: @jdehesa 
Sorry to be clear, I'm not trying to compute which of the X Y or Z axis has the most rotation. I want to find the 3d line that has the greatest rotation around it of any possible 3d line

Comment: @Birdfriender Ah so you mean just the axis of rotation then? Take the X, Y, Z components and that's it. Normalize if you want. Note that given a rotation axis `(vx, vy, vz)` and an angle `a`, the corresponding unit quaternion representing that rotation is `(W=cos(a/2), X=vx*sin(a/2), Y=vy*sin(a/2), Z=vz*sin(a/2))`, so the X, Y, Z components are proportional to the unit vector of the axis.

Comment: @jdehesa is that still true if more than one rotation could have happened? eg in this case if the user isnt holding their phone steady?

Comment: @Birdfriender I mean it comes down to the reference system for these quaternions. I don't know if they are "absolute" (i.e. current rotation wrt a reference position, akin to the coordinates of the mouse on the screen) or "relative" (i.e. current rotation wrt to previous position, akin to the delta in a mouse motion event). The "meaning" of the axis or rotation depends on the "meaning" of the quaternion.

Comment: @jdehesa im considering the motion relative to a starting position, so the latter

Comment: @Birdfriender Well then I suppose you'd have to keep composing the quaternion readings in order to get the equivalent quaternion wrt to the reference position. This may be prone to errors (if there is imprecision in the readings they will accummulate), but I'm not sure you can do much else.